# Matrix Multiplication of matrix and its transpose in Cuda

Tags: cuda

I am relatively new to CUDA programming so there are some unsolved issues for which I hope I can get some hints in the right direction.

So the case is that I want to multiply a 2D array with its transpose and to be precise I want to execute the operation A<sup>T</sup>A.

I have already used the cublas `Dgemm` function and now I am trying to do the same operation with a tiled algorithm, very similar to the one from CUDA guide.

The case is that while the initial algorithm runs properly, I want to calculate only the upper triangular matrix of the product hoping that I could achieve a better time for the operation, and I am not sure on how to extract tiles/blocks which will have the respective elements.

So if you could enlighten me on this, or give any hint I would be grateful, cause I have stuck on that for a while.

This is the code of the kernel

```
__shared__ double Ads1[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
__shared__ double Ads2[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];

//block row and column
//we save in registers for faster access
int by = blockIdx.y;
int bx = blockIdx.x;

int ty = threadIdx.y;
int tx = threadIdx.x;

int row = by * TILE_WIDTH + ty;
int col = bx * TILE_WIDTH + tx;

double Rvalue = 0;

if(row >= width || col >= width) return;
//Each thread block computes one sub-matrix Rsub of result R

for (int i=0; i<(int) ceil(((double) height/TILE_WIDTH)); ++i)
{
    Ads1[tx][ty] = Ad[(i * TILE_WIDTH + ty)*width + col];
    Ads2[tx][ty] = Ad[(i * TILE_WIDTH + tx)*width + row];
    __syncthreads();

    for (int j = 0; j < TILE_WIDTH; ++j)
    {   
        if ((i*TILE_WIDTH + j) > height ) break; //in order not to exceed the matrix's height

        Rvalue+=Ads1[j][tx]*Ads2[ty][j];
    }   
    __syncthreads();
}   
Rd [row * width + col] = Rvalue;
```

Comment: If you have the A(T)*A running correctly, and you want to extract the upper triangular matrix, why don't you show the code you have already to perform the A(T)*A multiplication?

Comment: this question isn't any better than the last time you asked it

Comment: Well,this is the first time i make a question on stack,so i am not quite sure what are you talking about

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508964/efficient-multiplication-of-transpose-with-original-matrix-in-cuda#comment70226167_41508964

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the batch dgemm API function described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemmbatched) recursely dividing your output matrix with block diagonal and corner. You also want to balance smallest block size versus overhead in compute to avoid small invokes. Finally, note that matrix multiply turns memory bound at some stage, which can be on modern GPU somewhat large.